# Mysql how to retrieve the data based on time?

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve the data from table based on the time and date i.e I need to get the data from yesterday 5.00pm to current day till 5pm. I have tried the following code in which I retrieved the yesterday and today but with time it is not working help to solve this problem note:the column modified is in timestamp

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mdl_forum_posts`
WHERE from_unixtime(modified, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
   OR from_unixtime(modified, '%Y-%m-%d') = date(CURDATE()-1)
```

Comment: If you're storing date-time values as UNIX timestamps you're in for a world of hurt. Don't do this. Use the `DATETIME` or `DATE` type instead. This allows easy indexing, and things like `BETWEEN ? and ?` where those are two arbitrary dates or date-time values.

Comment: storing date-time in unix timestamps is it not a proper way?

Comment: It might be in C programs, but it's not in any SQL database. Use the native column types whenever possible. The database engine is optimized around them both from a query simplicity perspective and performance.

Comment: may be i wont store the date-time in timestamp in future but i need to slove this problem using unix timestamp thank you for your suggestion

Comment: **THERE'S NOTHING INTRINSICALLY WRONG WITH USING UNIX TIMESTAMPS AS A DATA TYPE IN A SQL DATABASE** The values can easily be indexed and can be extracted using native operators *and without having to rely on non-portable/mysql specific date calculation functions*. I will agree that it is a bad idea in the absence of a client which does not natively use unix time to represent its data.

Comment: @tadman: how is it that you know more about Arun's application (of which MySQL may be a small part) than Arun does?

Comment: Someone's made a decision to use MySQL. That decision often has implications, and one of them is doing it the MySQL way unless you have a very compelling reason not to. Since that reason isn't specified, it's not a factor here. Some people prefer `time_t` or `MM/DD/YYYY` dates. MySQL doesn't. You'll have to face that reality, or spend all your time fighting it.

Comment: _"Since that reason isn't specified, it's not a factor here"_ No.

Comment: @tadman: "Hold your outrage" "Before you dog pile on". Would you maybe consider being a little less combative? We have a **[be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)** policy here. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The "outrage" here is the all-caps and bold text. There are occasions where `time_t` might be unavoidable. This does not appear to be one. Yelling about it helps nobody. I'm trying to be civil here.

Comment: why you all are fighting for such a small thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the date 1st of the month CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY gives exact previous day date

```
SELECT * FROM `mdl_forum_posts`
WHERE modified BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
           CONCAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' 17:00:00'))
         AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
           CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 17:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `mdl_forum_posts`
WHERE modified BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
         CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' 17:00:00'))
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
         CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 17:00:00'));
```

Note that CURDATE() is [polymorphic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate); the DATE_FORMAT is required for the first predicate where the calculation forces an integer-like return type.

Wrapping attributes in functions within predicates disables the use of indexes - applying the inverse function to the literal allows the for use of indexes (and even in the absence of indexes will be faster as the function need only be evaulated once).

Comment: There's an extra `AND` early in the query that needs to be removed.

Comment: till yesterday query has worked properly now query is not performing properly it  getting all the data

Comment: above answer fails if the date is 1st of the month

Comment: Yes - on my mysqld  (5.1.73) `SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) -1, '%Y-%m-%d' ) ` returns `2016-08-00` which is nonsense. But ` SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 1
DAY , '%Y-%m-%d' ) ` returns the expected value. Updating answer.